# formatting titles and legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, format, economics

I'm trying to format a chart using GGPLOT2. What I'm trying to accomplish feels like it should be fairly straightforward, but try as I might, no dice. I have the following chart.

```
#packages
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(timeSeries)
library(quantmod)
library(ggthemes)

#stock data
getSymbols(c("^FCHI","^GSPC"), from = "2008-12-31")
stockmarketdata <- cbind(GSPC$GSPC.Close, FCHI$FCHI.Close)
#normalize data
stockmarketdata$CAC40 <- stockmarketdata[,2] / 3217.97
stockmarketdata$SNP <- stockmarketdata[ ,1] / 903.25

#Isolate normalized data
marketdata <- stockmarketdata[,3:4]

GSPC.DF<-data.frame(Date=index(GSPC),coredata(GSPC))
FCHI.DF<-data.frame(Date=index(FCHI),coredata(FCHI))

#format before making ggplot chart
market.df <- data.frame(Date=index(marketdata), marketdata)
market.df.eco <- market.df
colnames(market.df.eco) <- c("Date", "CAC40", "S&P500")
market.df.eco.mlt <- melt(market.df.eco, id = "Date")
```

ggplot chart

```
chart.EQ <- 
  ggplot(market.df.eco.mlt, aes(x=Date, y=value, colour = variable, group = variable)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    labs(title="Equity Market", x= "", y = "", color="December 31st 2008=1", title.vjust=1) + 
    theme_economist() + 
    scale_color_economist() + 
    theme(legend.position = c(0,1), 
          legend.justification=c(0,1), 
          legend.direction="horizontal", 
          plot.title = element_text(vjust=1), 
          legend.title=element_text(vjust=1), 
          legend.title.align=0)
```

which looks like this

[image]

Ideally, I would like the title and legend to be flush with the left side. I would like both the legend and the title to be above the chart itself with the legend title directly below the chart title and the labels in the legend below the legend title. More like this.

[image]

If someone could help me with this formatting that would be excellent. Whenever I remove the justification argument from the theme(), the legend flies half way off the image. Thanks for any help you can offer!

If you don't have the finance packages here is a small sample of the data frame 'marketdata' if you apply the transformations from the code above you should be able to get a similar chart

```
marketdata<-
structure(c(0.999999990988107, 1.04093261932212, 1.04411163621786, 
1.05539205492904, 1.03981394730218, 1.03305191720246, 1.02533584837646, 
1.00874778726961, 0.993760008017477, 0.948424006438842, 0.930984404142985, 
0.937469895617423, 0.929060849231037, 0.909045152378674, 0.902920185085629, 
0.891748561049357, 0.885384230741741, 0.918395795175219, 0.918134733698574, 
0.955885235101632, 0.935294611198986, 0.92416023828687, 0.910527459547479, 
0.926792323421287, 0.953703729369758, 0.952864706321066, 0.970422359127027, 
0.9741763027623, 0.938712915285102, 0.94087886804414, 0.921183257768096, 
0.931599768487587, 0.920524420985901, 0.893491853559853, 0.893131405202659, 
0.892674604797434, 0.854746951960397, 0.847699051575994, 0.841539867991311, 
0.838081126300121, 1, 1.03160806864102, 1.02679215278162, 1.03481872349848, 
1.00376421145862, 1.0071740714088, 0.985718213119291, 0.963476346526432, 
0.965170194298367, 0.932875721007473, 0.934115682258511, 0.94117907002491, 
NA, 0.891469660669803, 0.930240786050374, 0.916136174923886, 
0.92106284195959, 0.926177699418766, 0.936296730694714, 0.967716608912261, 
0.935665668419596, 0.914342657071686, 0.913855523941323, 0.928325502352615, 
0.921372798228619, 0.936451675615832, 0.961638500968724, 0.963066720177138, 
0.915759726543039, 0.923044550235262, 0.924649877663991, 0.915405510102408, 
NA, 0.873700507057847, 0.872870172156103, 0.862374760033213, 
0.85253250816496, 0.82295047550512, 0.8559535178522, 0.846830915029062
), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1440080950.2661, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1230681600, 
1230854400, 1231113600, 1231200000, 1231286400, 1231372800, 1231459200, 
1231718400, 1231804800, 1231891200, 1231977600, 1232064000, 1232323200, 
1232409600, 1232496000, 1232582400, 1232668800, 1232928000, 1233014400, 
1233100800, 1233187200, 1233273600, 1233532800, 1233619200, 1233705600, 
1233792000, 1233878400, 1234137600, 1234224000, 1234310400, 1234396800, 
1234483200, 1234742400, 1234828800, 1234915200, 1235001600, 1235088000, 
1235347200, 1235433600, 1235520000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(40L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("CAC40", "SNP")))
```

Comment: It would help if made your example reproducible. Tinkering is easier when there's data to tinker with.

Comment: If you run the code as displayed. It should produce the example chart. The getsymbols() function should download the data from yahoo finance.

Comment: @Fanderson your code is reproducible, but it would be easier to help you if you just posted the data.frame to plot. Since your question is strictly about ggplot, you should avoid using finance packages that most people would probably need to install.

Comment: I hope that works @scoa